# Owl Carousel 2 loop false if item less than 3

Tags: jquery

How to make owl carousel loop false if item length is less than 3.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/b0hn2674/5/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check `<img>` length:

```
loop: $('.item img').lenght > 2 ? true : false,
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rkLvx3zy/2/

Comment: What if there are multiple sliders, 1 only have 1 image, but others have 4, 6, 3, the rule is, if it has less than 3 then loop false, but if more then loop true, same rule for all carousel that are triggers with the same class.